# Frobenius norm and Gaussian noise

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization

Why Frobenius norm is considered to a good tool for dealing with Gaussian noise?

Comment: This seems awfully vague. What do you mean by "deal with"?

Comment: If you are denoising by minimization of a functional involving the matrix norm, it helps to have a norm for which you can find the gradient analytically.